# Parse text file to model object

Tags: java, input, file-io

I'm trying to read text from file. Make parser to calculate STP
 trying to parse text into model:

```
`this is a text.txt`
[BRIDGE 1]
BridgeId = 42
[BRIDGE 1.Port 01]
PathCost = 10
ConnectedTo = LAN A
[BRIDGE 1.Port 02]
PathCost = 10
ConnectedTo = LAN B

[BRIDGE 2]
BridgeId = 97
[BRIDGE 2.Port 01]
PathCost = 05
ConnectedTo = LAN C
[BRIDGE 2. Port 02]
PathCost = 10
ConnectedTo = LAN A
[BRIDGE 2. Port 03]
PathCost = 05
ConnectedTo = LAN D

# Header 1 #
```

Класс Bridge - это роутер и соответственно Port это порты роутера 
Model classes :

Bridge.java:

```
public class Bridge {
    private int id;
    private int priority;
    private List<Port> ports = Collections.emptyList();

    public Bridge(int id, int priority, List<Port> ports) {
        this.id = id;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.ports = ports;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public List<Port> getPorts() {
        return ports;
    }
}
```

Port.java:

```
public class Port {
    private int portId;
    private int pathCost;
    private String connectedTo;

    public Port(int portId, int pathCost, String connectedTo) {
        this.portId = portId;
        this.pathCost = pathCost;
        this.connectedTo = connectedTo;
    }

    public int getPortId() {
        return portId;
    }

    public int getPathCost() {
        return pathCost;
    }

    public String getConnectedTo() {
        return connectedTo;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public List<Bridge> parseFile(String fileName) {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    List<Bridge> bridges = Collections.emptyList();
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            int bId = scanner.
            if (line.startsWith("[") && !line.contains(".")){
                bridges.add(new Bridge(line.next))
            };
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ;
}
```

So I get stuck here and can't figure out how organize parsing. 
Which object should be first at reading? Create Ports and then read lines 
and fill `Bridge`s by the List of Ports?

Comment: What do you mean by: `Класс Bridge - это роутер и соответственно Port это порты роутера` ?

Comment: I mean Bridge - LAN bridge(comutatur or switch), and it has a Port(s)

Comment: And you don't have any intention to edit that part of your question? Expect everyone to find out by themselves?